# PHP file() adding slashes to single quotes

Tags: php, file, quotes, magic-quotes

I have a PHP installation running 5.3.3 and when I use the code below:

```
    $sql = file('sql.txt');
    var_dump($sql);
```

All my single quotes are escaped.  Why would this be happening.  Magic quotes is enabled on the server (for some reason, it is out of my control) however I thought that magic quotes was only applied to GET POST COOKIE and REQUEST?  I there something else I am missing here with the latest PHP?

Any ideas?

Comment: magic quotes shouldnt be the problem, I've tested the same code in the same configuration and works like a charm, no backslashes. If you have no option, use stripslashes()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`magic_quotes_runtime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-runtime) causes this.  Thankfully, this "feature" is off by default, but apparently it's enabled on your server.

Answer (score 0):

From php.net:

> If magic_quotes_runtime is enabled,
>   most functions that return data from
>   any sort of external source including
>   databases and text files will have
>   quotes escaped with a backslash.